# Why is the difference between behaviors in for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am confused by getting the different results after executing the same loops after one another.
The first loop Increments the different way and second is completely different.

Results:

```
1 , 1
1 , 2
1 , 3
2 , 1
2 , 2
2 , 3
3 , 1
3 , 2
3 , 3
```

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int outerval {1}; outerval <= 3; outerval++)
        for(int innerval {1}; innerval <= 3; innerval++)
            cout << outerval << " , " << innerval << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You run  the inner loop inside the outer loop, so for each value of `outerval` the full range of `innerval`s will be printed.

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Corrected.

Comment: @IndianaJones I changed my comment accordingly

Comment: @j6t I expext the same result but it's not

Comment: Since the loops are nested, the `innerval` loop must complete in its entirety before the `outerval` loop can iterate a single time.

Comment: @0x5453 I Understand )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *nested* loop here. For each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop is completed. The output is hence to be expected. If you want to tear these loops apart, you can do so by

```
for(int innerval {1}; innerval <= 3; innerval++)
   cout << innerval << '\n';

for(int outerval {1}; outerval <= 3; outerval++)
    cout << outerval << '\n';
```

which will print

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Comment: Ok I Understand )

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a for loop it first finishes, whatever is inside it then it goes to the next iteration, so it first finishes the inner for loop and then the outer for loop enters the next iteration, then it finishes the inner again, etc.

If you want the two loops to iterate one after the other you'd do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    cout << i << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

result:

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: hmm helpful for me )

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes you are absolutely right he missed zeros